# Get variable by its name, which is stored in another variable

Tags: javascript

How can I select an array variable by its name?

This is what I'm doing so far to get the content in a dynamic way:

```
const lib1 = ['banana', 'apple'],
      lib2 = ['audi', 'bmw'];
let   index = 1;

lib1[index] // result: apple
```

Now I need to select the array-variable also dynamical:

```
let library = 'lib2',
    index = 1;

library[index] // wrong - but should result 'bmw'
```

Comment: `let library = lib2,`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If it's top level you can do `window[library][index]`

Comment: I need to do this in a function, and I do get the name as a parameter.

Comment: this.lib2[index] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the data structure a bit and access then with a key.

```js
var lib1 = ['banana', 'apple'],
    lib2 = ['audi', 'bmw'],
    object = {lib1, lib2},
    index = 1,
    library = 'lib2';

console.log(object[library][index]);
```

Comment: *"Advantage: it is not restricted to the global space"* - Local *or* global it is best to use an appropriate data structure for the job rather than separate variables, which in this case means organising each `libX` array within a single object just like you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use variable as a execute code ,if so try with `eval()`

```
eval(library)[index];
```